# Converting python list to dictionary

Tags: python

I want to convert list to dictionary.
Don't know how to do it)
for example:

```
info = [{'name': 'Bob','telephone': '12343', and etc.}]
```

Are there any built-in functions?

Comment: `info = info[0]`?

Comment: Ye, It looks like it, but the problem is in adding this fields to sqlite. It defines this as a list and I can't just add, for example info['name']

Comment: What were the error messages returned?

Comment: It's ok now, ty for help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary is inside the list, just take it from the list:

```
info = [{'name': 'Bob','telephone': '12343', and etc.}]
infodict = info[0]
```